# use gpg to decrypt file without prompt for passphrase

Tags: encryption, openpgp, passphrase

I have used below command and unable to proceed to decrypt file without prompting a window where user need to enter passphrase.  I have checked in google and stackoverflow and did not find solution to my question.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin>gpg --batch --passphrase-fd < "C:\Temp\test.txt" --decrypt ECUIDs-104066317-2018-03-09-09-10-15-500K_0000000000.bin
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID DA6F981CEBAE94FA, created 2018-01-11
  "GMECUPGPEncryption <gmecupgpencryption@xyz.com>"
gpg: public key decryption failed: Operation cancelled
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

Can someone provide me right input to solve this issue?

Thanks,
Srinivas

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

Comment: I am planning to call gpg utility through vb.net code to avoid manual intervention.  Before I execute in code, I was planning to get actual syntax by running manually.  I have found answer and may be useful to others.   gpg --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase testphrase -o <output directory with file name> -d <input file with complete path>

Comment: This is very much a programming issue the same way ssh is a programming issue.

Comment: This is a programming question, basically using gpg, with customize option u need to deal a lot with scripting. So question about this is not related to programming.. I believe OP is asking for the how to program (decrypt gpg without passphrase).